# How to remove line breaks between floated h1 tags?

Tags: html, css

Why is there a line break between the middle and last floated h1 tags?
[image]

```css
.div {
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-table;
  border-color: #91b8f7;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 55%">
  <div>
    <h1 style="display: inline-block; float: left;">1</h1>
    <h1 style="display: inline-block; float: right; padding-right: 60%">2</h1>
    <h1 style="display: inline-block; float: right; padding-right: 10%;">3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 30%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 15%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues with your code:

1- You need to add "box-sizing: border-box" to the CSS for the .div class. Without this, by default, your browser adds the width of the border to the width of your divs, so they are slightly more than the percentages you are telling them to be. Border-box makes the browser include the border in the width you set.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

2- You can't have any white space between your divs, or that tiny space will push your third div into the next line. I eliminated the spaces between the close of one  and the start of another . You can choose flex or grid display if you don't want to have to do this.

```css
.div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-table;
  border-color: #91b8f7;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 55%">
  <div>
    <h1 style="display: inline-block; float: left;">1</h1>
    <h1 style="display: inline-block; float: right; padding-right: 60%">2</h1>
    <h1 style="display: inline-block; float: right; padding-right: 10%;">3</h1>
  </div>
</div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 30%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 15%">
  <p>dsfdsfdsfsfds</p>
</div>
```